# how to log the wow network latency in to a file

Tags: networking, lua, latency, world-of-warcraft

I want log the wow network latency in to a file ,like c:/wowlatency.txt

now ,I can use some lua stript to log it into wow's chat log file.but I want log it to my own log file .can do this ?

Comment: maybe... what have you tried already?

Comment: Is this a Lua script from within "wow" (which I assume to mean "World of Warcraft", but it would be nice to get some confirmation on that)? If so, then Lua can only do what "wow" allows it to do. And if it doesn't allow you to write a file, then you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the infrastructure in place to monitor the latency (ie. calling [GetNetStats](http://www.wowwiki.com/API_GetNetStats) every 30 seconds), you can use Lua's built in File I/O facilities to open the desired log file:

```
local latencylog = io.open("c:/wowlatency.txt","w")

-- enter whatever loop you may have
  latencylog:write(message_string_about_latency)
  -- don't forget to write a \n if it's not in the string
  -- repeat

-- after finishing the log
latencylog:close()
```

Comment: I test this code,can't work, the wow may be don't accept the addons code wirte file to os. Now, I use the SavedVariables to resolve this.

Comment: now ,I use this code to do it..lt1={}

function ActionButton_OnUpdate() 
        if (MyAddon_LastTime == nil) then 
                MyAddon_LastTime = GetTime()
        else if (GetTime() >= MyAddon_LastTime + 30) 
        then             
                i, j, k, l = GetNetStats(); print(k) MyAddon_LastTime = GetTime()
                lt1[date("%Y-%m-%d %X")]=k
                end
        end
end

Comment: I had another question is ,how to flush the SavedVariables to the file in the game. in default, when the game quit, the saved variables will be write to the file.

Comment: If you have a another question, please ask it separately.